# Combining `others` expression with `signed` cast

Tags: vhdl, xilinx-ise

Let `var` stand for a signed vector (library IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL) of size `m`.

Let `foo` be another variable of type `std_logic_vector(n-1 downto 0)`, where n is smaller than m.

I want to concatenate a '0' left of `foo`, then pad it with zeroes in its right until it size is `m` and then store the result in `var`.

I tried

```
rdsor <= signed('0' & divisor & others=>'0');
```

But Xilinx complains with the following message on synthesis:

```
Syntax error near "others".
```

How do I do what I want?

Comment: You haven't supplied the declaration for `divisor,` nor `rdsor`,necessary to providing a solution. Note neither `var` nor `foo` appear in your one line snippet.  You've also omitted which revision of the VHDL standard your tool expects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `rdsor` is equivalent to your theoretical `var` and divisor equivalent to `foo` you could use two assignments in a process statement:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity jsevillamol is
end entity;

architecture fum of jsevillamol is
    constant M:     natural := 42;
    constant N:     natural := 23;
    signal rdsor:   signed (M - 1 downto 0);
    signal divisor: std_logic_vector (N - 1 downto 0);
begin
    -- rdsor <= signed('0' & divisor & others=>'0');
    process (divisor)
    begin
        rdsor <= (others => '0');
        rdsor (rdsor'LEFT downto rdsor'LEFT - divisor'LENGTH) 
            <= signed('0' & divisor);
    end process;
end architecture;
```

This works because each element of `rdsor` is a separate signal and there is only one value for any particular time in a *projected output waveform*. By not providing an `after` *time_expression* in the waveform element of the second assignment the elements of `rdsor` slice will be assigned the second assignments expression values. (The elements of the first assignment are supplanted by the second). This method of overwriting the projected output waveform is commonly used in providing default values prior to incomplete condition coverage with if statements.

This example analyzes, elaborates and simulates, while doing nothing interesting it demonstrates index ranges are constructed properly.

Notice it avoids the issue of concatenation versus aggregation brought up by Matthew Taylor's answer.

For a single signal assignment in a method not sensitive to tool VHDL revision:

```
architecture fie of jsevillamol is
    constant M:     natural := 42;
    constant N:     natural := 23;
    signal rdsor:   signed (M - 1 downto 0);
    signal divisor: std_logic_vector (N - 1 downto 0);
    subtype other is signed (rdsor'LEFT - divisor'LENGTH - 1 downto 0);
begin
    -- rdsor <= signed('0' & divisor & others=>'0');
    rdsor <= '0' & signed(divisor)  &  other'(others => '0');
end architecture;
```

This uses concatenation and subsumes the `others` into an aggregate. There's a subtype declaration for the trailing '0's portion to allow the aggregate expression to be the target of a qualified expression.

This architecture also analyzes, elaborates and simulates proving index arithmetic is correct.

Comment: Ups, I mixed up the names of the variables. Thank you for the exhaustive solution!

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use `others` as part of an *aggregate* not part of a *concatenation*. Here's a solution using an aggregate and *attributes* (which relies on you using VHDL 2008):

```
rdsor <= (rdsor'LEFT => '0', (rdsor'LEFT-1) downto (rdsor'LEFT-divisor'LENGTH) => signed(divisor), others => '0');
```

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/5Yuw

Comment: Notice the -2008 option.

Comment: @user1155120 You're right. Not for the first time, I have inadvertently come up with a solution that requires VHDL 2008, because that switch is set by default for Riviera Pro on EDA Playground.